# Сохранение данных!

Tags: разработка-игр, javascript

Здравствуйте, у меня есть своя игра написанная на js, она однопользовательская и естественно открывается через браузер.

Вопрос: Можно ли создать какой либо вид сохранений в игре? Если можно, то какой, и как приблизительно его можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Кроме кук и LocalStorage можно использовать хранилище данных flash'а или шифровать сохраненку и выдавать ее пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать хранить в кукис но пользователь может их потерять.

Comment: Я это рассматривал, но в куки насколько я знаю можно сохранять только переменные, а не действие всего скрипта.

Comment: Используйте JSON, в JSON формате запихивайте текущее состояние игры, при открытии - восстанавливаете данные их кук(если они имеются), profit

Answer (score 1):

Если игра ориентирована на html5 - используйте LocalStorage. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://freehabr.ru/blog/html/1041.html), естественно данные лучше хранить в JSON'e.

Если же нет, то как и писали выше - можно хранить и в куках.

Answer (score 0):

Если параметров в игре не много, то можно хранить на серваке,а людям приписывать куки. Что-то мне не кажется что твоя игра много памяти сожрет.
 А вообще почитай про [Локальное хранилище](http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage) если тебе верхний источник не понравился